# Require_relative in Ruby not finding files that do exist

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, require, shared-libraries

I am trying to use require_relative in ruby 1.9.2 to load a .so file in Mac OS X 10.6.8.  Require_relative is working properly for .rb files, but is claiming a .so file I am trying to load does not exist, even though it clearly does.

The documentation states I do not need to provide the extension (.rb or .so) when using require relative, but it doesn't make any difference. Using require with the full path does not work either.

```
Macbook-Pro:RubyCTest admin$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
Macbook-Pro:RubyCTest admin$ pwd
/Users/admin/Documents/Ruby/RubyCTest
Macbook-Pro:RubyCTest admin$ ls
Makefile    extconf.rb  test.rb
create.rb   sotest.so   test.rb~
Macbook-Pro:RubyCTest admin$ cat test.rb
require_relative 'create'
require_relative 'sotest'
Macbook-Pro:RubyCTest admin$ ruby test.rb
test.rb:2:in `require_relative': no such file to load -- /Users/admin/Documents/Ruby/RubyCTest/sotest (LoadError)
from test.rb:2:in `<main>'
Macbook-Pro:RubyCTest admin$ irb
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > require '/Users/admin/Documents/Ruby/RubyCTest/sotest.so'
LoadError: no such file to load -- /Users/admin/Documents/Ruby/RubyCTest/sotest.so
from /Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from (irb):1
from /Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 >
```

Comment: I think on OS X ruby won't look for .so files, since it expects native libraries to have the .bundle suffix

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much Frederick Cheung!

Comment: @FrederickCheung your comment should be an answer, and Strobecast you should accept it.